# Why does my email signature text color not showing in browser?

Tags: html, email, signature

I made a html signature and our company is using outlook but the text color is not showing on the browser. On mobile the signature is working fine. TIA

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 10px;">
    <div style=" font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style: bold;">Full Name</div>
    <div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; font-style:bold; color:gray;">Head of Business Development</div>
    <div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; font-style:bold;"> O: xxxxxxxxxx</div>
    <div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; font-style:bold;">M: xxxxxxxxxx</div>
    <div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; font-style:bold;">E:<a href="mailto:xxxxxxxxxx"> xxxxxxxxxx</a></div>
       <div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; font-style:bold;"><a style="color:#24bef2;">xx</a> <a style="color:#e9212c;">x</a><a style="color:#f16530;">x</a><a style="color:#804295;">x</a><a style="color:#1a9248;">x</a><a style="color:#aecf4c;">x</a>
        | <a style="color:#f06a4f;">xx</a> <a style="color:#00a3aa;">xxxxx</a> 
      | xxxxxxxxxxx</div>
    </div>
    
  <div small style=" font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:8px; color:#4d4d4e; padding-top: 10px">
      Confidentiality Notice: This e-mail message, including any attachments, is for the sole use of the <br>
      intended recipient(s) and may contain confidential and privileged information. Any unauthorized <br>
     review, use, disclosure or distribution of this information is prohibited, and may be punishable by<br>
      law. If this was sent to you in error, please notify the sender by reply e-mail and destroy all <br>
  copies of the original message. Please consider the environment before printing this e-mail.</small></div>

<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Validate your HTML and fix that one error first. There may be more than one.

Comment: Oh I just did, still not working :(

Comment: You did not fix it or did not post your fixed markup here.

Answer (score 0):

Each mail application has its own rendering engine, which determines how emails are displayed. You don't have 100% control over the signature. That's why some mail clients will show UNDERLINE for the link and <a herf=> tag not working color.